# Erro no adb: The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred

Tags: android, eclipse

Estou desenvolvendo para Android e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred.
 -You must restart adb and Eclipse.
 Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Program Files\Java\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Este erro ocorre ao tentar compilar qualquer projeto. Já atualizei o eclipse, porém ocorre a mesma coisa!

Já vi que tinha que, pelo console, dar um `adb kill-server` e depois `abd start`. Fiz isso mas não solucionou o problema.

Comment: Está usando o Genymotion?

Comment: não, uso dispositovo mesmo. mas com ou sem dispositivo conectado da o mesmo erro

Comment: Se ainda não resolveu o problema, chegou a fechar o eclipse, matar os processos do `adb` (todos) e abrir novamente?

Comment: Já tentou desligar e ligar novamente?

Comment: @WarLock já foi ver se o adb está mesmo na pasta?

Comment: Estou votando para fechar pelo seguinte motivo: A pergunta não tem uma resposta marcada como aceita e por se tratar de um erro de Android + Eclipse IDE dificilmente será útil para alguém nos dias de hoje. - *Se não estou enganado o Android não tem mais o ADT Plugin para Eclipse IDE*.

Answer (score 0):

Vc viu se o seu dispositivo aparece nas opções de dispositivos
quando vc executa o projeto ???

A opção de (desenvolvedor) esta destravada e também ligada
no seu smartphone??

Faça um teste assim:
Vai no seu projeto clica com botão direito vai em
RUN AS > RUN Configuration...
Na aba (Target) marque a primeira opção ( Always prompt to pick device )
Quando vc mandar rodar seu projeto vai aparecer uma janela de opções
de dispositivos conectados, caso não aparecer nenhum então ele não 
esta encontrando seu Smartphone.

XD;

Comment: Esta ativado a opção desenvolvedor, e fiz o que voce disse e continua dando o mesmo erro, com ou sem dispositivo conectado, o erro ja da na hora que mando rodar.

Answer (score 0):

> Gerenciador de tarefas
>
> > > Fechar processo: ADB.exe
> > >
> > > Fechar processo: Eclipse.exe

- Abra o eclipse novamente.

Answer (score -1):

1 - Via comando, acesse a pasta do seu android no caminho que contém o adb.exe:

> c:\seu_caminho\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\

2- Digite este comando:

> adb kill-server && adb start-server

3- Pressione Enter